# Hungarian Algorithm- what to do when some 'jobs' are unavailable to certain workers?

Tags: java, algorithm, hungarian-algorithm

In my program, there will be students (from multiple year groups/grades) submitting choices for activities running from Monday to Friday.

Each activity may be applicable to one, or multiple year groups. Each student has say 4 choices (1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th) per day. This is being stored in each student object as int[][] studentCosts which will be `studentCosts=new int[5][4]`.

I have finished my hungarian algorithm but I need to decide how to add all the students' choices to an int[][].

I will be executing the algorithm separately for each day, so I will need to collate all the students' choices for that particular day into an int[][] costsForThatDay.

My problem is with how some year groups may be offered certain activities which are not offered to others, for example, on Monday, **Year 7 are offered Windsurfing on Monday**, whereas **Years 8 and 9 are offered Golf on Monday**.

If I were to execute the algorithm by day would it be best to set the 'costs' for unavailable activities to something like `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to make sure there is absolutely no way it will ever be chosen? E.g. Make Golf 'cost' for year 7 students and Windsurfing 'cost' for year 8 and 9 students  `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: You can just set these to a value higher than the sum of all other activities together (so plus one for example) that way, the algorithm is never tricked into selecting that activity, unless there is no other way to do it (so there is a job, and nobody can do it), but then the problem thus can not be solved.

Comment: It should be the same using the sum of the costs and Integer.MAX_VALUE right? As long as its a large number. And do you mean the sum of all the costs for every student or the sum of the student's individual costs (1+2+3+4)?

Comment: no, the `MAX_VALUE` is not necessary, just the sum of all costs of combinations of persons and jobs that are possible is enough (plus one), since then picking that value would have a cost larger than any possible combination, hence the algorithm will never pick that, unless a valid combination is simply not possible.

Comment: Sum of the costs of all people, +1, got it. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful with MAX_VALUE, since HA implementations aren't always written to avoid integer overflow.

Comment: Ah yes, now that I think about it there are situations where values are added to create more zeros, which could cause overflow. :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You should make that an answer.